# How do I stop Xcode 9 from continuously building or at least make it not run build scripts?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

After migrating to Xcode 9, I noticed that it constantly fully builds my project. I found that it is somehow related to the "show live issues" setting. Disabling that setting stops builds, but it makes development inconvenient.

I would like to disable this continuous build loop, or make it work without launching all build scripts.

My custom build scripts contain linting and formatting, so what happens is, I try to edit a file, but Xcode starts building, thus launching the formatting routine that changes exactly the same file I am trying to edit.

Comment: Xcode 11.3 is building so often that, I am literally unable to open the menu suggestions mentioned below!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open any .storyboard file in your project and go to the Editor menu, uncheck **'Automatically Refresh Views'.**

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Any negative side effects to be aware of?

Comment: Worked for me , here is the same solution with Explanation

https://holko.pl/2017/11/15/rebuilding-ibdesignables/

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading the Xcode version to Xcode 9.0, I also faced a similar issue and my CPU usage was jumping upto 50% just because of Xcode. However I could solve it by following the steps below.

In the Toolbar go to:
**File** -> **Project Settings** / **Workspace settings** change **Build System** to **Standard Build Settings** under **Shared Workspace Settings**. Also under **Per-User workspace Setting** change **Build System** to **Standard Build System**.

The release notes also say the following.

> "Xcode 9 includes a new build system written from scratch in Swift. It
>   is designed for higher reliability, and it catches project
>   configuration problems that the standard build system does not. The
>   performance of the build system (not including compilers, linkers, and
>   other build tools) has been dramatically improved."

So there could be a possibility that there are still bugs in the new build system.

Comment: I will try if I catch it again. In my case it somehow went away after building project manually and switching back and forth "show live issues" setting.

Comment: Did you catch it again? And what's your current "show live issues" setting?

Comment: I upgraded to Xcode 9.1 (Stable release). The issue got fixed in that for me automatically.

Comment: It still happens. Looks like ti is related to @IBDesignable.

Comment: https://holko.pl/2017/11/15/rebuilding-ibdesignables/ Please go through it.   @IBDesignable is responsible for the continuous building the project

Comment: Hmm, in Xcode 11.3 there is no more "Standard Build Settings".  Just some new **"New Build System"**  :/